# InvalidOperationException Web Application

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I'm not very familiar with how this works, but I'm trying to submit and calculate the entered amounts for either deposit or withdraw, but now I'm getting this error: InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

[image: The entire error]

I feel like I need a fresh set of eyes on this because I'm mentally stuck.

BankAppModel.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Proj1BankApp.Models
{
    public class BankAppModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a transaction month.")]
        public string TransactionMonth { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a transaction day.")]
        [Range(1, 31, ErrorMessage = "The transaction day must be between 1 and 31.")]
        public int TransactionDay { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a transaction year.")]
        public int TransactionYear { get; set; }

        public decimal? Balance { get; set; }

        public decimal? WithdrawAmount { get; set; }

        public decimal? DepositAmount { get; set; }

        public decimal Deposit()
        {
            decimal balance = 0;
            balance = Balance.Value + DepositAmount.Value;
            return balance;
        }

        public decimal Withdraw()
        {
            decimal balance = 0;
            if(Balance.Value < WithdrawAmount.Value)
            {
                return balance;
            }
            else
            {
                balance = balance - WithdrawAmount.Value;
                return balance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Proj1BankApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Proj1BankApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.BankApp = "";
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(BankAppModel obj, string submit)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.BankApp = obj.Deposit().ToString("c2");
                ViewBag.BankApp = obj.Withdraw().ToString("c2");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.BankApp = "";
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that inside your `Deposit` method has `Balance` or `DepositAmount` null value. Try to put breakpoint there and check if these properties have null value assigned.

Or you can add null check like (in the same way inside `Withdraw` method):

```
public decimal Deposit()
{
     decimal balance = 0;
     if(Balance.HasValue && DepositAmount.HasValue)
     {
        balance = Balance.Value + DepositAmount.Value;
     }
     return balance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your nullable field has value before call its value property.